# watcher in angular directive not triggering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created my own directive and watching an attribute like this:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('pieController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    function initData() {
        var arr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            arr.push(parseInt(Math.random() * 100));
        }
        return arr;
    }

    var data = initData();
    $scope.data = data;

    $scope.changData = function () {
        var data = initData();
        $scope.data = data;
    }

}]).directive('eChart', [function () {

    function link($scope, element, attrs) {

        var myChart = echarts.init(element[0]);

        if (attrs.myOptions) {
            $scope.$watch(attrs.myOptions, function () {
                var options = $scope.$eval(attrs.myOptions);
                if (angular.isObject(options)) {
                    myChart.setOption(options);
                }
            }, true);
        }
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };
}]);
```

and the html is like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="pieController">
        <button ng-click="changData()">click me</button>
        <div e-chart my-options="{tooltip: {show: true},
        legend: {
            data: ['销量']
        },
        xAxis: [
            {
                type: 'category',
                data: ['衬衫', '羊毛衫', '雪纺衫', '裤子', '高跟鞋', '袜子']
        }
        ],
        yAxis: [
        {
        type: 'value'
        }
        ],
        series: [
        {
        'name': '销量',
        'type': 'bar',
        'data': {{data}}
        }
        ]}" style="height: 400px;width: 100%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my controller,i change the value of the attribute,but the watcher doesn't trigger.

So what i am doing wrong?Thanks.

[here is code in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keller35/eet08q8o/)

Comment: Sorry for my english cause i am a chinese and really hope your help

Comment: What data the ``changeData`` function in controller trying to change and if you console.log() ``attrs.myOptions`` then do you see updated data ??

Comment: The `changeData` function is trying to change the `data` in $scope,and this `data` is also bind to the attribute `my-options` 。

Comment: I can not console.log `attrs.myOptions` cause the watcher does't work

Comment: possible to create fiddle or plunker replicating this problem ??

Comment: i created one,here is the link.http://jsfiddle.net/keller35/eet08q8o/

Comment: Cant get it work, but would like to know what you are trying to achieve?? desired output ??

Comment: just wanna know why it cant work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `attrs.$observe`
You directive should be like this

```
 .directive('eChart', [function () {
    function link($scope, element, attrs) {

        element.text("innerText");

        //监听options变化
        if (attrs.myOptions) {
            attrs.$observe('myOptions', function () {
                console.log("变了")
                var options = $scope.$eval(attrs.myOptions);
                element.text(attrs.myOptions);
            })
        }
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };
}]);
```

Comment: If you think this answer solves your problem plz accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you should bind the data directly.

```js
app.directive('eChart', [function() {
    function link($scope, element, attrs) {
        if (attrs.myOptions) {
            $scope.$watch('data', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (angular.isObject(newValue)) {
                    console.log('change');
                }
            }, true);
        }
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            data: '=myData'
        },
        link: link
    };
}]);
```

```html
<div e-chart my-data="data" my-options="... your options ..."></div>
```